# Store the component list and make it default for future installations

Tags: inno-setup

The thing that I would like to achieve is to store somewhere in an `.ini` file or in an  `.xml` file, the components that were selected by a user, and when he installs future releases the same components he had chosen the first time to get auto-selected as default.Also, I need to give up some information such as: `Unnistalable = No` , so can't call the registry's and I'm not planning to make it Unnistalable, so if it's possible to get an answer i would be very grateful.

Regards,
BeGiN.

Comment: Selecting previously chosen components already happens. You just need to use the same `AppId` and use the same component naming for all your updates.

Comment: but it's working with the Unnistalable = No ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood your question...

Comment: Yeh well i'm trying to do that without calling registry .. :-(

Comment: I see now. Well, there's one (big) weakness with the only solution I can think of by now. Since you can't access component names in components container, you can uniquely identify a component only by its description which is tied to no change of a description in your script nor using a different language by the user. So if you'd change a description of the same component in the future, or the user would select a different language as in the last installation, the settings would not be loaded. And that might be limiting.

Comment: Well if it's too hard to do  , than it's not needed mate :D , i can live without... but i was thinking about an index or something i remember the components got indexes , isn't that right ?

Comment: That's of course possible. But what if your update setup will need to insert some subcomponent somewhere near to the beginning of the list and the rest of it will be reindexed ?

Comment: hmm :D well you know .. my installer's name is kinda like this `Mod-Pack 8.11.22 by BeGiN` which 8.11.22 it's my version which is changing a lot :D so if i make it unninstalable  the user will gotta unninstall the older version first .. than to install the newer version which is kinda more difficult than now :D if there would be any way to make it Unninstalable but the users wouldn't need to unninstall / install it would be awesome :-)

Comment: Using different output file name is definitely not a reason to prevent your application to be uninstallable if that was the reason to use `Unnistalable=no`. There might be options for you. You can simply overwrite the previous installation with the newer version. Or automate uninstallation of the previous one. It depends on your requirements...

Comment: That was my reason to use `Unnistalable  = no` and my entire inno setup knowledge it's base on that `Unnistalabe = no` :( always found a way to workaround that :D

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the [`AppId`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) directive in your script. Use this directive with some unique name in your current script and keep it same in all your subsequent updates and let the Inno Setup handle all the updating hard work for you. This directive uniquely identify your application regardless what you use in other directives. It also allows the setup to append to uninstall logs or load previous installation settings (which includes component settings).

Comment: Oh, and of course, when you'll be using `AppId`, don't forget to remove `Uninstallable=no` from your script :-)